# Cardinality of Boolean algebras generated by partitions and some eextra elements.

Tags: boolean-algebra

Consider a parttion of the unity of a finite Boolean algebra and two different elements of the algebra. What is the cardinality of the algebra generated by the union of the partition and the set consisted of the two elements?

Extend the problem to the case of countably infinite partitions.

Any ideas?